# Django views can't open .csv file by using pandas [IOError]

Tags: python, django, file-io, pandas, django-views

I got IOError when I open .csv file in `views.py`, it says I don't have the file in the directory, here is my directory:

```
/survat         #theproject
    /survatapp  #theapp
        /modules
            __init__.py
            survat_core.py
        __init__.py
        views.py
        forms.py
        models.py
        prostate1.csv
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py        
/database
        sqlite.db
/media
/static
    /bootstrap
```

Here is the traceback

```
    Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/graph.png

Django Version: 1.4.1
Python Version: 2.7.9
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'survat.survatapp')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Milexjaro\Dropbox\Thesis2\survat\survatapp\views.py" in showimage
  129.     printaalen('prostate1.csv','dtime','status1','age','hg','sz','sg','pf','rx')
File "C:\Users\Milexjaro\Dropbox\Thesis2\survat\survatapp\views.py" in printaalen
  105.         prostate_dataset=pd.read_csv(args[0])
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py" in parser_f
  465.         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py" in _read
  241.     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py" in __init__
  557.         self._make_engine(self.engine)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py" in _make_engine
  694.             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py" in __init__
  1061.         self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)

Exception Type: IOError at /graph.png
Exception Value: File prostate1.csv does not exist
```

And my `views.py` be like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from survat.survatapp.models import Document
from survat.survatapp.forms import DocumentForm
from django.http import HttpResponse
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lifelines import CoxPHFitter,AalenAdditiveFitter
from django.http import HttpResponse
from matplotlib import pylab
from pylab import *
import PIL, PIL.Image, StringIO
from survat.survatapp.modules.survat_core import printall

def showimage(request):    
    def printaalen(*args):
        # module_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)  # get current directory
        # file_path = os.path.join(module_dir, 'prostate1.csv')
        # prostate_dataset=pd.read_csv(file_path)
        prostate_dataset=pd.read_csv(args[0]) #<-- This is the issue
        prostate_dataset=prostate_dataset[list(args[1:])]
        pdplot=prostate_dataset[list(args[3:])]
        for x in prostate_dataset:
            if (prostate_dataset[x].dtype=="object"):
                cat=pd.Series(list(prostate_dataset[x]))
                for y in pd.unique(cat):
                    prostate_dataset[x+'.'+y]=pd.get_dummies(cat)[y]
                prostate_dataset.drop(x, axis=1, inplace=True)

            else:
                pass

        aaf=AalenAdditiveFitter(fit_intercept=False)
        aaf.fit(prostate_dataset,args[1],event_col=args[2])
        aalenListPlot=list(prostate_dataset.columns.values)[2:]
        aalenPlotTemp=[]
        for x in aalenListPlot:
            aalenPlotTemp.append(aaf.plot( columns=[ x ], color='red' ))

        return aaf.plot( columns=[ 'age','hg' ], color='red' )

    printaalen('prostate1.csv','dtime','status1','age','hg','sz','sg','pf','rx')

    xlabel('X Bar')
    ylabel('Y Bar')
    title('Significance of dataset')
    grid(True)

    # Store image in a string buffer
    buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
    canvas = pylab.get_current_fig_manager().canvas
    canvas.draw()
    pilImage = PIL.Image.fromstring("RGB", canvas.get_width_height(), canvas.tostring_rgb())
    pilImage.save(buffer, "PNG")
    pylab.close()

    # Send buffer in a http response the the browser with the mime type image/png set
    return HttpResponse(buffer.getvalue(), mimetype="image/png")

def list(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('survat.survatapp.views.list'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form

    # Load documents for the list page
    documents = Document.objects.all()

    def delete_matrix():
        documents = Document.objects.all()
        for document in documents:
            document.delete()

    ae=printall('prostate1.csv','dtime','status1','age','hg','sz','sg','pf','rx')

    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render_to_response(
        'survatapp/list.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form': form, 'ae':ae},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

when I open the `#` signs in:

```
# module_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)  # get current directory
# file_path = os.path.join(module_dir, 'prostate1.csv')
# prostate_dataset=pd.read_csv(file_path)
```

and give `#` sign in:

```
prostate_dataset=pd.read_csv(args[0])
```

it gives `attribute error`:

```
'tuple' object has no attribute 'method'
```

what should I do? Thanks in advance

UPDATE 6/11/2015: Adding complete path and complete code in `views.py`, and I realized something, when I delete `list` function in `views.py` the graph worked just fine, I think there is a clash between `list` function and `showimage` function. Here is the attribute error traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/graph.png

Django Version: 1.4.1
Python Version: 2.7.9
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'survat.survatapp')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Milexjaro\Dropbox\Thesis2\survat\survatapp\views.py" in showimage
  129.     printaalen('prostate1.csv','dtime','status1','age','hg','sz','sg','pf','rx')
File "C:\Users\Milexjaro\Dropbox\Thesis2\survat\survatapp\views.py" in printaalen
  106.         prostate_dataset=prostate_dataset[list(args[1:])]
File "C:\Users\Milexjaro\Dropbox\Thesis2\survat\survatapp\views.py" in list
  24.     if request.method == 'POST':

Exception Type: AttributeError at /graph.png
Exception Value: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'method'
```

Comment: Is the current working directory correct? You may need to add a more complete path

Comment: Nope @EdChum, but I wrote a more complete path and complete views.py code.  I'm sorry I think it lead to a total confusion. I think there is something wrong with `if request.method == 'POST'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Adding complete path and complete code in views.py, and I realized
>   something, when I delete `list` function in views.py the graph worked
>   just fine, I think there is a clash between list function and
>   showimage function"

Yes, indeed. Naming your view function `list` shadows the builtin type `list` in your whole module's namespace, so in `printaalen()` when you try to use the builtin list type you instead call your view function.

TL;DR : don't shadow builtin names.

Comment: it works seamlessly after I alter the function name, thanks a lot @bruno-desthuilliers :)